# Is it possible to get any folder created within a directory is being created with 777 permission?

Tags: permissions, mkdir

I have one requirement in which when I create a directory I want to create it with 777 permission. I did all stuff but not able to do this, anybody knows how to do this? Then please share.

Suppose I have directory `/home/sachin/dir`.

Now I am creating one folder `test` under `/home/sachin/dir`.

```
mkdir /home/sachin/dir/test
```

It will create `test` folder with 775 permission which I do not want.

I don't want to use `-m` option with the `mkdir` command.

Comment: You have to use umask, added an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `umask` command:

Execute this command for creating every file or directory with 777 permission for an interactive shell:

```
umask 000
```

If you want to make it permanent setting for a single user then execute following commands:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

and add a new line as

```
 umask 000
```

then save the file.

If you want to make it default setting for all users, then execute following commands:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/profile
```

and add a new line as

```
 umask 000
```

then save the file.

Comment: I want set umask for only test user then also i have add umask 000 into .profile file ?

Comment: I added umask 000 into /home/test/.profile and save the file, after that i create a file and that file was created with 644 permission. Any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: @sachin changes in ~/.profile require re-logging in to take effect.

Comment: I did, I reboot the server but still file not create with 777 permission.